# What does URL.openStream() return?

Tags: java

According to the docs, it returns an InputStream. But also according to the docs, InputStream is an abstract class. So which particular subclass does .openStream() return?

Comment: The point of encapsulation is that you don't know or care.

Comment: Also, you can simply do `.getClass()` on the stream returned to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of encapsulation is that you don't know or care.
You just use it as an `InputStream`, and whatever it returns will behave as you expect.
It could even return a different class on Sundays if it wanted to, and you still wouldn't know or care.

Reading [the source](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#1605), it looks like HTTP URLs return an instance of an internal class called `HttpInputStream`.